# Android Studio emulator causing BSOD with DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION error on Windows 11

Tags: android, bsod, windows-11, android-studio, emulator

whenever I try to run the device emulator, my pc crashes and shows blue screen of death because of DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION.
I've tried: [completely uninstalling everything related to android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39953746/12782605) and installing it again, updating my graphics card drivers and i've made sure virtualization is enabled in my bios, but the issue still persists. I'm not sure what else to try at this point.
Using BlueScreenView, I can see the bsod was caused by ntoskrnl.exe driver. My CPU is Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8400 CPU @ 2.80GHz, I have 16.0GB of ram, only 1 HDD (no ssd) TOSHIBA DT01ACA100 and NIVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti for gpu and B360 - A308 chipset. [WinDbg results from !analyze -v](https://pastebin.com/raw/3qCNFvcW).

Comment: You can use [BlueScreenView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to get more details on the components involved in this bluescreen. may be you can identify the driver causing it. Please also update your question and include more details about your PC, like CPU model, chipset, available RAM...

Comment: @Robert Hi! updated the question with the information you asked for

Comment: You need to use WinDBG in my experience BlueScreenView is inaccurate. You can provide the relevant information for the analysis we can give you our thoughts

Comment: @Ramhound added the WinDbg results.